# How to get value of a Volley XML response?

Tags: android, xml, android-volley

I write a Volley StringRequest and get a XML response. How to get the value of "CurrentVersion" for example ?

My XML response as below :

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    <?xml version="1.0"?> <Result xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> <IsSuccessed>true</IsSuccessed> <Code>1</Code> <Message>{ "CurrentVersion": "108.12.16.1", "ForceUpdate": false, "EnableO365": true, "Description": "" }</Message> </Result>
    </string>
```

My Volley StringRequest as below :

```
String HttpUrl ="https://m.fbl.com.tw:1114/Fubon/pss/FubonWebservice.asmx/GetActiveAppVersionEx?appCode=fubonmapp2&platformName=AndroidPad";
            RequestQueue mQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity.this);

           StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, HttpUrl,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {

    Log.i("TAG", response.toString())

                        }

                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                    Log.i("TAG", error.toString());

                }
            });

            mQueue.add(stringRequest);

        }
```

Comment: Go through this [link](https://medium.com/@ssaurel/parsing-xml-data-in-android-apps-71ef607fbb16). It is a good example of xmlpullparsing. It may help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `StringRequest` to get your response and parse it in `public void onResponse(String response)`.

Answer (score 0):

Create StringRequest having response type String. Once you will get callback in *public void onResponse(String response)* method, you can parse sting XML data using XML parser library and you XML convert into Model class.